# What are the categories of IND and PRO schemes?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes, algebraic-stacks

I have some difficulties to figure out what the category of IND-schemes and PRO-schemes are...

Are they full subcategory of algebraic stacks? Are they full subcategory of algebraic spaces?

Edit: I think my question can be misleading, let me clarify it. I know what are ind-object and pro-object. I also know when ind-schemes are actual schemes and when pro-schemes are actual schemes (which is for both, rather rare). My question is: when they are not schemes, are they at least alg. stack or alg. spaces?

Comment: Does https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/ind-object answer your question? Ind-blah are directed systems of blah, and maps between them are what would be needed to obtain a map between their direct limits, if those existed. Dually for pro-blah.

Comment: Not really, I should have been more clear in my question, I apologies. I know what are ind-object and pro-object. I also know when ind-schemes are actual schemes and when pro-schemes are actual schemes (which is for both, rather rare). My question is: when they are not schemes, are they at least alg. stack or alg. spaces? I'm going to edit.